# How to remove Company field from checkout process in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, theme, uicomponent

How to remove Company field from checkout process in Magento 2? I've been looking for the template but have not found it.

**Update:** Is there any way to remove this field via layout or template?

Comment: I can't check at the moment as I'm on my phone, but I think it's related to a Knockout JS template. Is there anything in the form you can search for, such as a class or id?

Comment: Shipping fields are inside: `form id="co-shipping-form"`. Code for commpany field: `<div class="field" name="shippingAddress.company" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses">"`

Answer (score 17):

Temporarily, we should try:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

For example, in  `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`, find the component that you need to customize. Copy the corresponding node and all parent nodes up to . We're going to remove/disable telephone and company fields:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Remove fields-->
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**[EDIT]:**

From Magento 2.2.x

<del>**STORES > Configuration > Customersmers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Company > No**</del>

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Here is the same question: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3373#event-547267751

Comment: STORES > Configuration > Customersmers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Company > No
This code works perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

I have hide the company field in `**Magento 2.1**` using below steps:

Copy handle file in `app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

replace the below code:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
</item>
```

with

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                                                                                                
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
</item>
```

Comment: It's enough use only `<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>`

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for coding,simply go to 
Stores > Configuration > Cutomers > Customer Configuration
then in Name and Address Options You set Show Company to No

Comment: That actually removes the field. Correct. All the other answers in this thread only hide the field.

Answer (score 6):

Magento Provide Backend Configuration for Company display or not in CHeckout.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should try to set false to visible attribute:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  `vendor / magento / module-checkout / view / frontend / layout / checkout_index_index.xml`

find:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
</item> 
</item>
```

Replace:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>  
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
</item>
</item>
```

Comment: it's for Magento 2.1.9

Comment: you are recommending edit to the core which is not good, replace with proper way to set this value using best practices

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merely *disable* a field instead of removing it altogether use this:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Note: I know this is not what OP is asking for but I'm just putting it here in case anyone finds it helpful.