# Magento 2 - making company required causes error on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

When I set company to required under **config -> customer information**.

After that I got this error when tap/click on next/continue button.

```
Please check the shipping address information. company is a required field.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This link may help you to check your error. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/how-to-remove-company-field-from-checkout-process-in-magento-2

Comment: That just hides it, I've turned it on and required. But it then causes an error in the next continue step. It works if I set it to not required but its not ideal.

Comment: @user2353244, you mean you have set company field required and even after filling company field you are getting error ?