# magento2: How to remove zipcode from billing address in checkout process

Tags: checkout, billing-address, magento2.3.4

I want to remove zipcode and Street Address field from billing address from checkout process.

I am able to remove the above field from shipping address successfully using this [article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/how-to-remove-company-field-from-checkout-process-in-magento-2/)

Please help me how to remove these field from billing address.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your issue. You need to setup the checkout option in the configuration so that billing address is on payment page. There is a possibility to work it out otherwise, however, my solution only caters for this specific scenario.

[image]

Once the above is setup,

you may create a plugin, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="layout_checkout_process" type="Mbs\RemoveCheckoutField\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutProcess" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and the plugin needs to remove the fields (do bear in mind, the backend may need further changes as streets fields are mandatory in billing details..)

```
namespace Mbs\RemoveCheckoutField\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class CheckoutLayoutProcess
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        if ($this->isBillingOnPaymentPage()) {
            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
                ['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']);

            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
                ['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']);
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    private function isBillingOnPaymentPage()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkout/options/display_billing_address_on');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have created the plugin and able to remove the fields from billing address, but when I am trying to remove street field it give error, So first I need to remove required validation for street field, can you please help me to remove the required validation?

Comment: let's do one thing at a time, please acknowledge whether this answer validates your question. Then, please do create a question on a separate thread, I can't promise I will take a look at it. If I find the question interesting, I do try to take a look if time allows

Comment: Please check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312876/magento2-how-to-remove-required-validation-from-street-field-in-billing-address),  mean while I am trying to implement your solution